How to light an LED when a 3 cell 11.1v Li-ion battery is fully charged
I'm trying to create a charging notification module for a 3-cell 11.1 V Li-ion battery.
The battery has a built-in BMS, and a 12 V DC adapter (with a 12.6 V output) is connected for charging it.
What I have tried is, I've attempted to reduce the battery voltage using a voltage divider to bring it into the 5 V range, which is then fed to the input of a comparator (LM339 op-amp) along with a constant 5 V reference using a Zener diode.
An LED is connected to the output of the comparator, so when the battery voltage exceeds the reference voltage, the LED lights up.
The issue I'm facing is that during charging, the voltage from the battery always reads 12.6 V (5 V after the voltage divider), as the charger voltage seems to be measured instead of the actual battery voltage.
Is there any way to measure only the battery voltage and pass it to the comparator input?
I have tried reading many posts similar to this, but none of them had an answer (or I didn't understand) about how to measure the battery voltage and ignore the charger voltage.

Consider measuring the current instead of the voltage. In the absence of any fault condition, if the power brick is sourcing significant current, then the battery is charging. If not, then either the battery is fully charged, or it is disconnected.

The battery terminals will NEVER have 12.6V on it. Vbatmax is 4.2V cell almost always. Some few cells allow 4.25V or 4.3V. You need to find the positive connection point to the actual battery. negative is usually common. Vbat will assume 8.4V at end of constant current charge phase. The voltage will then stay at 8.4V and current will reduce. You can either find the charger end-of-charge signal (if there is one) or stop charging when 8.4V is reached. State of charge will then typically be in the 80%-90% range. If that's tolerable stopping then will greatly increase battery cycle lifetime.

@RussellMcMahon My mistake, actually the battery is 3 cell, I thought I wrote 3 cell battery in the question.

3 cells makes it more complex BECAUSE 3 cells are usually fully charged at 3 x 4.2 = 12.6V.  ||What is the device/brand/model. It is seldom done but a VERY rough and ready device may use a supply set to 12.6VDC as the charger. BUT you may be seeing the battery voltage AND it may be fully charged. You say " ... always reads 12.6V ..." --> If that is with the charger disconnected then the battery is charged. If with charger connected, remove the charger. Read voltage. If zero then find true battery point. If between about 9V and 12.6V it is probably the battery.

|| A voltage with charger disconnected immediately after disconnection and then after running for say 15 minutes without charging will give a reasonable indication of what you are seeing.


the charger voltage is read instead of the actual battery voltage

Is a bit wrong. There's exactly one voltage between two points, in this case the two contacts of the battery. The actual voltage is the voltage impressed on the battery. There's no "more actual voltage" than that!
So, what you need to do is infer the charge state in a different way.
Many, if not even most, battery charge controller ICs have some sort of pin that exports information on the charge state. If that is not the case for your battery, you can also combine checking the voltage against a minimum threshold, and the charging current (the current flowing from charger to battery) being low. You'll then also need to measure the current of your load (i.e., the LED) and subtract that from your charging current measurement it as soon as the LED turns on – because that current is primarily going to come out of the charger.
With an integrated BMS, you probably also want to take temperature into account – the fact that the charging current is low might also be  because your batteries got hot. You might not be able to sense that temperature externally: Battery packs typically have a thermal sensor directly attached to the batteries.
So, all in all, not an easy undertaking, unless your BMS is like I'd expect most BMSes and has a pin giving you exactly what you need.

Ok, thanks for the info. I'll check the BMS circuit if I can get the charging data

You must measure the voltage across the battery itself, which has nothing to do with the 12.6V charger supply. The BMS is likely to be current limiting, which means that even if 12.6V is applied, the BMS will "drop" a volt or so. If you are lucky, then the charger supply and battery negative will be connected together:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If that's the case, then you can power your monitoring circuit from the charger supply (between S and G), while monitoring battery positive potential at B (also with respect to G), but you must take B from the physical battery, not the external BMS positive terminal:

simulate this circuit
R4 is probably necessary to fine tune the exact switching threshold, since potentials will be inexact due to component tolerances. In particular D1 voltage will not be exactly 5.1V.
R6 and R7 provide positive feedback, for a tiny bit of hysteresis, so that when the thing trips it will stay tripped until power is removed, instead of oscillating.
Node OUT is pulled low (illuminating the LED) when battery voltage \$V_B\$ reaches +11.1V. This is the simulated response:


Ok, I'll try to do this way
